# Exporting Data from Google Sheets using Google Sheets API with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, google-sheets-api, cmder

I am facing problem :
 I have code copied from Google Sheets `v4` API `Node.js` [Quick start](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs), changed it a bit `findString()`,
& run it in command line using `Cmder` throws Error:

> "The API returned an error: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain".

Now, i could solve it permanently: using this command 
`set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` ,
 but after restarting machine i have to do it again.
 My question is, what can i do not to have to enter this command every single time i restart my machine?

Comment: I did, but couldn't find solution

Answer (score 1):

Add at the very beginning of your nodejs code the following line

```
 process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0
```